# Stashing without changing the index or the working tree

Tags: git, git-stash

In *Git from the Bottom Up* John Wiegley suggest running a cronjob throughout the day that calls git stash followed by git stash apply. I appreciate the idea of having hourly (or even more frequent) snapshots of my work, but I'm afraid that the build could break if a file momentarily disappears or reverts to HEAD. Is there another way to accomplish the objective, without running this risk?

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
git branch -f autosave $(git stash create)
```

This will force the branch `autosave` to update to a newly updated stash object. `git stash create` saves but doesn't touch your index and working tree. You can rely on the reflog of `autosave` to find previous versions just like stash does.

Answer (score 0):

```
git update-ref refs/stash $(git stash create)
```

This creates a stash (and it can be referenced and is saved just like all other stashes) without modifying the working directory or the index.

([Source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-stash.sh))